# Xiomi Redmi Note 4 phone Install this app via usb, remember my choice coming every time app installation

Tags: android, appium, redmi-device

Using redmi note 4 for mobile automation testig with appium. While executing the tests every time it is asking to install this app via usb and remember my choice radio button. I have enabled following options in developer options:

- USB debuging mode: enabled
- Install via USB: enabled
- USB Debugging (Security settings): enabled
- Verify apps over USB: enabled
- Turn on MIUI Optimization: disabled

Please share info if you had faced same issue. Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aASJ.jpg)

Comment: Is there a requirement to enable install via USB?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure don't enable verify app's over usb and give a try. Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue. "Verify app's over usb" is disabled. (MIUI 11, Redmi 7A)

Comment: this solved it for me thx!